# Use a loop to find the minimum of a vector without using the min() or sort() functions

Tags: r, function, loops

This is what I have but apparently I have it all wrong because it's not working :-\

```
set.seed(1)    
x <- runif(25)

sort<-function(x) {
   for(last in length(x):2) {
      for (first in 1: (last-1)) {
         save<-x[first]
         x[first]<-x[first + 1]
         x[first+1]<-save
      }
   }
   return(x)
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are doing this?

Comment: homework, or masochism, or some bigger context that you haven't told us about?  Do you really want to find the minimum?  That's not what your code looks like, and the function is called `sort`, and it doesn't have any `if` statements ...

Comment: Looks like homework. And having it all wrong would appear to be an understatement here.

Comment: Check your curly brackets. They don't all match up.

Comment: Can you use `which.min` or `order` functions?

Comment: What about using `rank`?

Comment: `range(x)[1]` done.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the algorithm. One option is to start with the first element of the vector as the target and then compare that with the second element. If the second is smaller than the target, set target to the second element. Repeat this comparison with target for elements 3 through n where n is the length of the vector.

```
findMin <- function(x) {
  minX <- x[1] ## set target to first element of `x`
  for (i in (seq_along(x[-1]) + 1)) { ## i take values 2, 3, ..., length(x)
    if(x[i] < minX) ## do comparison with current target
      minX <- x[i]  ## if element i is smaller than target, update target
  }
  minX
}

> set.seed(1)
> vec <- runif(20)
> min(vec)
[1] 0.06178627
> findMin(vec)
[1] 0.06178627
```

Quite *why* you want to do this is beyond me and the result is silly, inefficient R code. But (I think) this does what you want, at least what the title of your Q asks for.

Comment: Thank you, I'm relatively new to R and learning programing and functions in R. This question was an exercise to become familiar with using Loops.  I could have easily used sort(x) or min(x) to find the answer but it specifically stated not to